# How to make a new index column if id is being reset to 1 everyday and it has to be connected with other columns?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data that looks like this

| tx_id | tx_date | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/4/2023 | 3 |
| 1 | 1/4/2023 | 5 |
| 2 | 1/4/2023 | 3 |
| 3 | 1/4/2023 | 1 |
| 4 | 1/4/2023 | 1 |
| 4 | 1/4/2023 | 5 |
| 1 | 1/5/2023 | 5 |
| 1 | 1/5/2023 | 1 |
| 2 | 1/5/2023 | 4 |
| 2 | 1/5/2023 | 6 |
| 3 | 1/5/2023 | 1 |

Quick explanation for the columns
`tx_id` is a transaction id
`tx_date` is a transaction date
`product_id` is a product id

The behavior of the data here is that the `tx_id` being reset to 1 if the day changed

I was expecting to update the data to be like this by using pyspark / pandas
Take a quick look at the new id number 4 and 5

| id | tx_id | tx_date | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1/4/2023 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | 1/4/2023 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 | 1/4/2023 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 | 1/4/2023 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 | 1/4/2023 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 | 1/4/2023 | 5 |
| 5 | 1 | 1/5/2023 | 5 |
| 5 | 1 | 1/5/2023 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 | 1/5/2023 | 4 |
| 6 | 2 | 1/5/2023 | 6 |
| 7 | 3 | 1/5/2023 | 1 |

A quick explanation of what I was expecting is how do I make a new id column with index based on the `tx_id`, `tx_date`, and `product_id`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide some code, showing what you have tried so far. How you do want to combine these columns to get a new one?  Do you want to, for example, add them as a string?

Comment: `df['id'] = df.gropuby(['tx_id', 'tx_date']).ngroup() + 1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work (in pyspark):

```
df.withColumn("new_id", F.dense_rank().over(Window.orderBy(col("tx_date"), col("tx_id")))).show()
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

If uniqueness of the index is your main concern, resetting the entire dataframe index can be helpful.

```
df=df.reset_index(drop=True)
```